# Constrain an SVG object loaded with <use> to the dimensions and position of another rect object

Tags: svg

I am trying to reuse/recycle objects on my canvas using `<use>`, which is working fine so far.

However, I want specify the position and the size of the reused objects in vector application (e.g., Illustrator). Thus, I thought, drawing a `rect` which provides `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` may seem to be a good starting point.

In other words, the bounding box of a rect element should be the constraints for the reused object. See example below.

However, I struggle with:
(1) the positioning, which is relative to the linked object when I use `<use>`, and the rect’s `x`, `y` are thus not working.
(2) Scaling an object in `<use>` is not working at all (apart from `transform: scale(x)` which is also repositioning it, as it is not scaling in place (I guess the reference anchor needs to be set to center to fix this)

Anyone, know how to get this to work?

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
    y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1366 768" xml:space="preserve">
    <g id="fish">
        <path fill="#66BB6A" d="M579.41,70.53c-1.91-1.08-4.32-0.96-6.12,0.3l-8.7,5.76l-3,2.28c-2.58-1.2-5.82-2.4-9-3.6V63.81
        c0-3.3-2.7-6-6-6c-6.3,0-11.04,1.8-13.92,5.28c-1.37,1.44-2.34,3.24-3,5.28c-12.06-2.64-26.34-4.56-43.08-4.56
        c-11.28,0-22.5,7.92-23.88,8.88c-0.06,0.06-0.12,0.12-0.12,0.12l12,15l-9.6,9.6c4.86,8.34,15.6,8.4,15.6,8.4h12v6
        c0,2.4,1.44,4.62,3.72,5.52c0.72,0.36,1.5,0.48,2.28,0.48c1.56,0,3.12-0.6,4.26-1.74l10.2-10.26h3.54c4.44,0,8.76-0.36,13.02-0.96
        c2.22,8.1,8.28,12.96,16.98,12.96c3.3,0,6-2.7,6-6c0,0-0.06-12.48-0.12-12.72l9.12-2.28l11.7,7.98c0.96,0.66,2.16,1.02,3.3,1.02
        c0.96,0,1.92-0.24,2.82-0.72c1.98-1.02,3.18-3.06,3.18-5.28v-24C582.59,73.59,581.39,71.55,579.41,70.53z" />
        <path opacity="0.2" enable-background="new    " d="M561.59,78.87v8.94h-87l-12-15c0,0,0.06-0.06,0.12-0.12
        c1.38-0.96,12.6-8.88,23.88-8.88c16.74,0,31.02,1.92,43.08,4.56c8.88,1.98,16.56,4.44,22.92,6.9
        C555.77,76.47,559.01,77.67,561.59,78.87z" />
        <path opacity="0.3" enable-background="new    " d="M488.09,72.81c0,2.48-2.02,4.5-4.5,4.5s-4.5-2.02-4.5-4.5s2.02-4.5,4.5-4.5
        S488.09,70.32,488.09,72.81z M552.48,99.12c0.03,0.23,0.1,0.45,0.1,0.69v12c0,3.32-2.68,6-6,6c-8.7,0-14.75-4.85-16.99-12.97
        C537.94,103.67,545.73,101.51,552.48,99.12z M513.07,105.81l-10.24,10.24c-1.15,1.15-2.68,1.76-4.24,1.76
        c-0.77,0-1.55-0.14-2.3-0.46c-2.24-0.92-3.7-3.12-3.7-5.54v-6H513.07z M582.59,75.81v24c0,2.21-1.22,4.25-3.17,5.29
        c-0.89,0.47-1.86,0.71-2.83,0.71c-1.16,0-2.33-0.34-3.33-1.01l-11.67-7.99V78.87l11.67-8.05c1.84-1.23,4.21-1.34,6.16-0.3
        C581.37,71.56,582.59,73.59,582.59,75.81z M546.59,57.81c-9,0-14.7,3.66-16.92,10.56c8.88,1.98,16.56,4.44,22.92,6.9V63.81
        C552.59,60.51,549.89,57.81,546.59,57.81z" />
    </g>
    <g id="bat">
        <path fill="#616161" d="M799.29,87.2l9.87,28.43l-29.37-9.4c-7.35,1.29-16.53,5.6-16.53,19.19c0,0-28.9-15.71-35.7,9.79v-34.27
        c18.83,0,29.91-5.56,35.67-9.84l-10.17-14.64h10.2l5.1-4.9v-9.79l15.25,9.76c4.46-5.53,10.25-16.17,10.25-34.24h35.7
        c-26.77,6.12-10.2,34.27-10.2,34.27C805.1,71.56,800.61,80.19,799.29,87.2z" />
        <path opacity="0.3" enable-background="new    " d="M799.29,87.2l9.87,28.43l-29.37-9.4c-6.91-2.23-12.83-9.45-16.56-15.12
        l-10.17-14.64h10.2l5.1-4.9v-9.79l15.25,9.76C788.89,74.25,795.52,79.52,799.29,87.2z" />
    </g>
    <rect id="placeholder-fish2" x="502" y="174" fill="#CCCCCC" width="36" height="36" />
    <rect id="placeholder-fish3" x="486" y="258" fill="#CCCCCC" width="68" height="68" />
    <rect id="placeholder-fish4" x="464" y="395" fill="#CCCCCC" width="114" height="114" />
    <rect id="placeholder-fish5" x="449" y="583" fill="#CCCCCC" width="142" height="142" />
    <rect id="placeholder-bat2" x="757" y="174" fill="#CCCCCC" width="36" height="36" />
    <rect id="placeholder-bat3" x="741" y="258" fill="#CCCCCC" width="68" height="68" />
    <rect id="placeholder-bat4" x="719" y="395" fill="#CCCCCC" width="114" height="114" />
    <rect id="placeholder-bat5" x="704" y="583" fill="#CCCCCC" width="142" height="142" />


    <use xlink:href="#fish" id="fish2" y="100" />
    <use xlink:href="#fish" id="fish3" x="0" y="200" />
    <use xlink:href="#fish" id="fish4" x="0" y="350" />
    <use xlink:href="#fish" id="fish5" x="0" y="550" />

    <use xlink:href="#bat" id="fish2" x="0" y="110" />
    <use xlink:href="#bat" id="fish3" x="0" y="200" />
    <use xlink:href="#bat" id="fish4" x="0" y="350" />
    <use xlink:href="#bat" id="fish5" x="0" y="550" />

</svg>
```

Comment: instead of a <g id="fish"> try using a symbol or an svg element with a viewBox like `<svg id="fish" viewBox="462 57 122 62">` now use it with the position x y and the size width height you need.  Preserve the same aspect ratio for the use element

Comment: Okay, this allows me indeed to control the width/height and position of elements reused with `<use>`, but the positioning is way of. I am unable to get to the correct values to position the reused fish/bats in the respective circles. What is the positioning calculation here?

Comment: x and y are the coords of the left upper corner of the bounding box of the use element

Answer (score 0):

I actually solved it in a different way, which works great for my specific use case (non-programmer friendly). Yet, this solution is tailored to Adobe Illustrator and a preprocessing script.

Within Illustrator, I export my object that I want to reuse as SVG and PNG.

I then drag the PNG file into my SVG composition (this will create a link when exported as SVG, Illustrator uses `xlink:href` to refer to the file. I still create placeholder squares, as they contain my desired target size and location (height/width, x,y).

My script is looking for *.png file extensions and replaces those with *.svg. Illustrator puts some transform attributes on the image element, which can be removed. Then copy all attributes from the rectangle objects to the image element.

The lookup ids should match apart from the prefix: the square placeholders are e.g., `ph-fish1` and `link-fish1`. So my script can match those objects.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
    y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1366 768" xml:space="preserve">
    <rect id="ph-fish1" x="502" y="174" fill="#CCCCCC" width="36" height="36" />
    <rect id="ph-fish2" x="486" y="258" fill="#CCCCCC" width="68" height="68" />
    <rect id="ph-fish3" x="464" y="395" fill="#CCCCCC" width="114" height="114" />
    <rect id="ph-fish4" x="449" y="583" fill="#CCCCCC" width="142" height="142" />
    <image x="502" y="174" width="36" height="36" id="link-fish1" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
    <image x="486" y="258" width="68" height="68" id="link-fish2" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
    <image x="464" y="395" width="114" height="114" id="link-fish3" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
    <image x="449" y="583" width="142" height="142" id="link-fish4" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
</svg>
```

[image]

Then the placeholder elements can be removed from the SVG DOM

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px"
    y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1366 768" enable-background="new 0 0 1366 768" xml:space="preserve">
    <image x="502" y="174" width="36" height="36" id="link-fish1" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
    <image x="486" y="258" width="68" height="68" id="link-fish2" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
    <image x="464" y="395" width="114" height="114" id="link-fish3" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
    <image x="449" y="583" width="142" height="142" id="link-fish4" xlink:href="fish.svg">
    </image>
</svg>
```

[image]